# OSX Mavericks system wide Stereo upmixing

Tags: macos, audio, surround-sound, 5.1

I have been trying to figure out take the 2 channel output from my mac running mavericks.
- iTunes
- Safari
- Quicktime
- Etc.

And upmix to use all the speakers in my 5.1 surround sound.

[image: MIDI Setup]

I would like the left channel from the stereo mix to play on Left Front and Left surround and the right channel should play on right front and right surround.

I have tried Jack Pilot and SoundFlower both of mix do not seem to work correctly on mavericks.

If anyones has any ideas that would be great!

Comment: How are you connecting the mac to the speakers/amp? What interface are you using?

Comment: I am using a USB external sound card. The speakers are connected to it over 3.5mm cables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you choose channel 1 under both left front and left surround, and channel 2 under both right front and right surround?

*Edit: The above does not work. Maybe I found a solution but I cannot test yet since my 8-channel DAC did not yet arrive.*

Solution: install Apple's AU Lab and add a new configuration (it's the "+" button at the bottom) under user configuration, where you can define input and output channels. You have a matrix mixer to route channels as you wish.

Comment: Its been a long time since I had this issue I eventually solved it using a 3.5mm jack splitter very hacky solution. 

I think I did get it working with the AU Lab but I think my problem was I would always need to have AU Lab open to get it to work.